# Cannot add value to suspect type array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

`private ArrayList<Suspect> accomplices = new ArrayList<Suspect>();`

```
public void checkAndAddAccomplice(Suspect aSuspect) {

    for(int i=0; i<aSuspect.getAccomplices().size(); i++) {
        if(!(aSuspect.getName().equals(aSuspect.getAccomplices().get(i).toString()))) {
            accomplices.add(aSuspect);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code and i dont know why but the array stays empty even after this method.
This is starting to become really frustrating.

Comment: You mean aSuspect.getAccomplices().get(i).getName() instead of aSuspect.getAccomplices().get(i).toString() ?

Comment: Add System.out.println() statements in the code to print the value of `aSuspect.getName()` and of `aSuspect.getAccomplices().get(i).toString()`. Or use your debugger. This is basic debugging. You should be able to do that by yourself.

Comment: Even if i remove the whole if statement the array stays empty.

Comment: I am using the debugger but i cant find out why the arrays stays empty even after using .add()

Comment: The ArrayList **doesn't** stay empty after the add (this is its definition). The only reasonable conclusion for this code is that you don't execute any 'add' calls.  The cause must be that aSuspect.getAccomplices() is empty or that the if-condition is always false.

Answer (score 0):

you should be comparing aSuspect.getName() with aSuspect.getAccomplices().get(i).getName(), instead of aSuspect.getAccomplices().get(i).toString()

```
if(!(aSuspect.getName().equals(aSuspect.getAccomplices().get(i).getName()))) {
```